# How to display table from the database using json response in Android? (I'm getting JsonArray Fail error in this code)

Tags: java, android, mysql, json

This is Attendance.java file

```
package com.glbwebsim;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TableLayout;
import android.widget.TableRow;`
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.TableRow.LayoutParams;

public class Attendance extends Activity
{

    static InputStream iStream = null; 
    static JSONArray jArray = null;
    static String json = "";


     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)

     {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.fragment_main7);

            Button details = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mydetails);


            details.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
            {
            @SuppressWarnings({ "deprecation", "unused" })
            public void onClick(View view) 
              {
                 String result = null;
                InputStream is = null;

                try{
                        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://frndz4ever.com/glbsim/attend.php");
                        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost); 
                        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                        is = entity.getContent();

                        Log.e("log_tag", "connection success ");
                     //   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "pass", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                        Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Connection fail", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
                //convert response to string
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                try
                {
                        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
                        String line = null;
                        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) 
                        {
                                sb.append(line + "\n");
                              //  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Input Reading pass", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                        is.close();

                        result=sb.toString();
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                       Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), " Input reading fail", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }

                //parse json data
                try
                {

                JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray("["+result+"]");


                String re=jArray.getString(jArray.length()-1);


                TableLayout tv=(TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.table);
                tv.removeAllViewsInLayout();




                   int flag=1;

                for(int i=0;i<re.length();i++)

                        {




                                TableRow tr=new TableRow(Attendance.this);

                                tr.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                                           LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                                           LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

                                  if(flag==1)
                                {

                                    TextView b6=new TextView(Attendance.this);
                                     b6.setText("Roll_no");
                                     b6.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                                     b6.setTextSize(18);
                                     tr.addView(b6);


                                    TextView b19=new TextView(Attendance.this);
                                     b19.setPadding(10, 0, 0, 0);
                                     b19.setTextSize(18);
                                     b19.setText("Subjects");
                                     b19.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                                     tr.addView(b19);

                                   TextView b29=new TextView(Attendance.this);
                                 b29.setPadding(10, 0, 0, 0);
                                     b29.setText("Present");
                                     b29.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                                     b29.setTextSize(18);
                                     tr.addView(b29);

                                     TextView b30=new TextView(Attendance.this);
                                     b30.setPadding(10, 0, 0, 0);
                                         b30.setText("Absent");
                                         b30.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                                         b30.setTextSize(18);
                                         tr.addView(b30);


                                 tv.addView(tr);

                                     final View vline = new View(Attendance.this);
                                          vline.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 2));
                                          vline.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);



                                tv.addView(vline);



                               }

                                else
                                {



                                   JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);

                                   Log.i("log_tag","Roll_no: "+json_data.getInt("Roll_no")+
                                              ", Subjects: "+json_data.getString("Subjects")+
                                              ", Present: "+json_data.getInt("Present")+
                                              ",Absent: "+json_data.getInt("Absent"));




                            TextView b=new TextView(Attendance.this);
                                String stime=String.valueOf(json_data.getInt("Roll_no"));
                                  b.setText(stime);
                                b.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                                b.setTextSize(15);
                                tr.addView(b);


                               TextView b1=new TextView(Attendance.this);
                                b1.setPadding(10, 0, 0, 0);
                                b1.setTextSize(15);
                                String stime1=json_data.getString("Subjects");
                                 b1.setText(stime1);
                                b1.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                                tr.addView(b1);

                              TextView b2=new TextView(Attendance.this);
                             b2.setPadding(10, 0, 0, 0);
                                String stime2=String.valueOf(json_data.getInt("Present"));
                                b2.setText(stime2);
                                b2.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                                b2.setTextSize(15);
                                tr.addView(b2);

                                TextView b3=new TextView(Attendance.this);
                                b3.setPadding(10, 0, 0, 0);
                                   String stime3=String.valueOf(json_data.getInt("Absent"));
                                   b3.setText(stime2);
                                   b3.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                                   b3.setTextSize(15);
                                   tr.addView(b3);

                                  tv.addView(tr);


                        final View vline1 = new View(Attendance.this);
                      vline1.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 1));
                      vline1.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                      tv.addView(vline1);       


                                }

                       }}




                catch(JSONException e)
                {
                        Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "JsonArray fail", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                    return;


           }
              });
           }}
```

I'm getting JsonArray fail error on click of the button.
Please help.

**LogCat:**

```
04-20 20:54:37.458: D/StrictMode(9281): at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1151) 04-20 20:54:37.458: D/StrictMode(9281): at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.recvfrom(BlockGuardOs.java:163) 04-20 20:54:37.458: D/StrictMode(9281): at libcore.io.IoBridge.recvfrom(IoBridge.java:506)
```

Comment: also share the json string you are trying to parse

Comment: here it is  :   04-20 20:54:37.458: D/StrictMode(9281):  at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1151)
04-20 20:54:37.458: D/StrictMode(9281):  at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.recvfrom(BlockGuardOs.java:163)
04-20 20:54:37.458: D/StrictMode(9281):  at libcore.io.IoBridge.recvfrom(IoBridge.java:506)

Comment: json string is already in the code which im parsing.

Comment: You should use AsyncTask to perform any Network activity.

Comment: @MTahir How to use AsyncTask??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the code below for reference, it might have errors, its just to get an ides how it works.

Any network activity should be performed in `doInBackground`.
Do not perform any action on UI.

Once the `doInBackground` is complete, the data is returned to `onPostExecute`.
Now you can perform your UI actions here.

```
public class Attendance extends Activity {


    static InputStream iStream = null;
    static JSONArray jArray = null;
    static String json = "";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)

    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button details = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mydetails);

        details.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @SuppressWarnings({ "deprecation", "unused" })
            public void onClick(View view) {

                new makeHTTPRequest().execute();

            }
        });
    }

    private class makeHTTPRequest extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        String result = null;
        InputStream is = null;

        try {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://frndz4ever.com/glbsim/attend.php");
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            is = entity.getContent();

            Log.i("log_tag", "connection success ");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection " + e.toString());
            // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Connection fail",
            // Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
        // convert response to string
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();

            result = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result " + e.toString());

        }

        return result;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        // parse json data
        try {

            JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
            String re = jArray.getString(jArray.length() - 1);

            int flag = 1;

            for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){

                    JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(0);

                    Log.i("log_tag",
                            "Index: "+ i + " Roll_no: " + json_data.getInt("Roll_no")
                                    + ", Subjects: "
                                    + json_data.getString("Subject")
                                    + ", Present: "
                                    + json_data.getInt("Present")
                                    + ",Absent: "
                                    + json_data.getInt("Absent"));

            }

                    // Perform any required actions here


        } 
        catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "JsonArray fail",  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }

}
```

}

I have updated the private class `makeHTTPRequest`

dont forget to add

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`

under the `uses-sdk` tag

And this is the `Logcat` output:

```
04-21 23:37:13.904: I/log_tag(14032): Index: 0 Roll_no: 70, Subjects: Multimedia, Present: 20,Absent: 10
04-21 23:37:13.905: I/log_tag(14032): Index: 1 Roll_no: 70, Subjects: Multimedia, Present: 20,Absent: 10
04-21 23:37:13.905: I/log_tag(14032): Index: 2 Roll_no: 70, Subjects: Multimedia, Present: 20,Absent: 10
04-21 23:37:13.905: I/log_tag(14032): Index: 3 Roll_no: 70, Subjects: Multimedia, Present: 20,Absent: 10
```

First try this, if it works, add code step by step to enhance your app.

Comment: What to add in parameters -protected String doInBackground(String... params) ?

Comment: nothing,  use the above to try calling your server and check if you receive any response

Comment: My app force closed :(

Comment: 04-20 23:37:46.328: I/ActivityManager(601): START u0 {cmp=com.whatsapp/.ContactInfo (has extras)} from pid 5096
04-20 23:37:46.419: I/ActivityManager(601): Displayed com.whatsapp/.ContactInfo: +78ms
04-20 23:37:51.074: I/ActivityManager(601): START u0 {cmp=com.whatsapp/.ContactInfo (has extras)} from pid 5096
04-20 23:37:51.204: I/ActivityManager(601): Displayed com.whatsapp/.ContactInfo: +108ms
04-20 23:37:52.625: V/DeadZone(687): consuming errant click: (116.0,23.0)

Comment: Do you know how to use logcat ? search for some tutorials/examples. And also for `AsyncTask` search for tutorials and examples. You need to know how things work before using them.

Comment: I dont know how to use logcat but can you help me in this code?

Comment: 04-21 15:18:12.928: E/log_tag(25237): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value [{"Present":"20","Absent":"10","Subject":"Multimedia","Roll_no":"70"},{"Present":"21","Absent":"7","Subject":"D.S","Roll_no":"70"},{"Present":"19","Absent":"4","Subject":"M.C","Roll_no":"70"},{"Present":"19","Absent":"4","Subject":"NCER","Roll_no":"70"}] of type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject

Comment: I have updated my answer a bit, remove the extra `[]` and make it `new JSONArray(result);` in onPostExecute and give it a try, your json is valid

Comment: Its showing the same error, and the same logcat, please help @MTahir

Comment: I have updated the code, not much changes but tested and have shared the output as well. If you are still getting any error. Try removing unnecessary code, start small and then enhance your app step by step.

Comment: ohh Thanks a lot. let me try this

Comment: logcat error, select your app from the left to get only your app's log ?

Comment: I have tested the above code with a single activity, it works. Try with a new clean project.

Comment: 04-25 11:13:00.848: E/log_tag(18852): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: No value for Subjects

Comment: Its `Subject` in josn not `Subjects` :)

Comment: Can you help me with one more thing??

Comment: Every one here will help you, you can start a new question for your new issue :)